# Android: Why does my Spinner haven't got the standard design?

Tags: android, spinner

In my app I'm using a spinners to let the user select an item from a list. Everything works fine but I'm not really happy with the look of the spinner. As you can see in the image below it has the same design as a normal button.

[image]

What I want is a spinner which looks more like a normal text field. So I browsed a little bit through the drawable folder of the Android sources and found out that the spinner background should normally look quite different. I append an image of a spinner with the background image as I found it in the drawable folder. Although the spinner in the image is focused, I think you can see the difference between both spinners.

[image]

Now I'm wondering why the my spinner (first one) doesn't have the same design as the second one as II didn't changed any attributes which are related to the design of it. Where does this button like design come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first spinner screen depicts the default spinner.

So the answer is that you've expected the wrong behavior. You can however create your own spinner look.

Comment: Ah OK, I'm just wondering when the other spinner design will then be used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the second spinner was there in the earliest versions of the android sdk and just remains there as is.